# Speed up Adobe CQ5 Maven build

Tags: maven, maven-3, aem

I need solution to speed up maven build process.

The project is based on Adobe cq5 otherwise AEM and i have more than 10 modules in my project where the build happens in linear way.

Currently Build process takes more than 10 min to compile.

is any other specific tool available or other way to speed up the process?

Thanks

Comment: How long took you build? Which Maven Version do you use? Have you taken a look at `mvn -T 3.0 clean package` (maven 3.X) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "modules"? Different projects with own pom.xml or something else?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific to get a useful answer, about what exactly is slow, which phases/modules etc. Building ten small modules with Maven would be very fast on a good box once all dependencies are downloaded locally.

Answer (score 1):

I have one suggestion,If you have 10 modules than make separate profile for each module,and build only that part in which you are changing and modifying,no need to deploy 10 modules each time unnecessarily.It will not speed up maven project build but can help you to save your time.It is a workaround but will be helpful .

Answer (score 1):

Try `mvn -T 4 clean install` #Builds with 4 threads

Its a multi-threaded mode to run Maven and is faster. [Apache documentation here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3).

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers:

1) Give more memory resources to the server where the AEM instance is installed, content creation involves a lot of disk access so using SSD is a must.

2) Having a clean AEM instance helps to speed up the process. As you may know the AEM repository grows because of revisions so each time you deploy the repository size grows and it becomes slower. if it's a production environment use maintenance tools like revision clean up and compaction.

[revision clean up](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/revision-cleanup.html)

[how to maintain repository](https://www.netcentric.biz/blog/is-your-repository-growing-rapidly-in-aem6.html)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there are no such mechanism to speed up. 
better to make a build of particular module, it will deploy faster rather waiting for all 10 module to be happened.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the suggested answers to build modules in parallel. It should speed up the build in theory.

But really there is no magic answer. You have to find the bottleneck in your build, it could be the number of dependencies, it could be a specific slow plugin, it could be hardware related, and it could be something else.

Try this: https://github.com/lptr/maven-time-tracker

It may help you find the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer this question, knowing it was posted a really long time back. 
Currently I am using AEM 6.3 and to recompile and deploy CORE module changes there is a simple maven trick  -

[image]

This command tells us to -

- run 1 thread/core
- compile just the core module of the list of projects
- and of course, zip package and send it to running AEM instance.

In my observation, this reduced the turnaround time by a huge margin.